# Set default radio button in Woocommerce using Javascript

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm working on a WC Appointment Bookings product, and I managed to set up a default for a simple numeric field using a custom script:

```html
// Set default value to 0 for Input multiplier (for additional hours)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.addon-input_multiplier').val("0");
});
```

But I can't tweak that script to set a radio button to be a default. Here's the HTML of the button I want to make the default...

```html
<p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-520-language-0-0">
  <label><input type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-520-language-0[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="spanish"  /> Spanish </label>
</p>
```

For the numeric field, I put the id into the Javascript, but the radio button doesn't have an id. I can't tweak the HTML, because it's generated, and this doesn't seem like something that would require getting into the PHP.

What am I missing?

Comment: Update: I now have a radio button selected, but it's the last one, not the first one, which is what I want. Here's the partially successful code:


`// Set default value to Spanish for Language
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery( "input[name='addon-520-language-0[]']"   ).prop('checked',true);
    });'

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Here's the line I needed:

```html
     jQuery( "input[name='addon-520-language-0[]'][value='spanish']" ).prop('checked',true);
```